# Ctrl + shift + Z undoes when it should redo

Tags: feature-request, bug, editor, firefox, windows-10

I switched to a Windows computer recently.

On Mac, typically apps and websites have the shortcut to redo as <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>. On Windows the shortcut is typically <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>.

On Stack Exchange on Mac, in the editor for questions <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> also works to redo, but on Windows the Mac convention is not provided as an alternative, with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> actually undoing.

**Can this be changed to make <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> redo, or at least make it not undo?** This would be much more user-friendly to people used to Mac.

(I am on Firefox 78.0.1 on Windows 10.0.18363 Build 18363).

Comment: I am not so sure that this feature is under control of the SE engine, are you?

Comment: I have just tried it, and it does not undo.

Comment: I second the previous comment. `Ctrl` `shift` `z` does not undo anything on Stack Exchange on my Windows computer.

Comment: I also can't reproduce, but I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it is under websites' control -- if you go to SE chat it redoes, in Google Docs it redoes, etc.

Comment: `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Z` works fine to redo on Windows 10 2004 on Chrome 83.0.4103.116 and Firefox 78.0.1. This is a bug specific to you it seems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not undo, it already *does* redo.  Here is a simple test:  Go to the answer box below, type something, and delete it.  Then click the undo button, and you will see the redo button highlight.  Instead of clicking it, click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, and it should redo what you did.
I have done this in Chrome and in Firefox.

Comment: You're right, this bug does not happen now.